# Uses and drawbacks of C++ template parameters specifying a class' base classes?

Tags: c++, templates, multiple-inheritance, variadic-templates

## Background

Recently I have been thinking about how to design a particular piece of software and at one point I have crafted the following piece below:

```c++
template <typename ... Mixins>
class Foo : public virtual Mixins... {
    /* ... */
};
```

The idea that I had was the ability to augment a basic class with additional properties or behavior depending on the needs of the user. Say one application needs to use `Foo`s with an identification number. Maybe some other application needs to be able to talk about `Foo`s with a color. These needs can be fulfilled by adding the following classes:

```c++
class HasID {
    int m_id = -1;

public:
    int getID() { return m_id; }
    void assignID(int id) { m_id = id; }
};

class HasColor {
public:
    int color = 0;
};
```

## Questions

My two questions about this code are as follows:

1. What are the uses and drawbacks of using templates like this?
2. Does this particular pattern have a name?

## Additional example code

Here is an additional example that showcases it's possible to print details of an object of an augmented class.

Print functions:

```c++
// Default printBase
template <typename Base>
void printBase(std::ostream& out, Base& x) {}

// printBase for HasID
template <>
void printBase(std::ostream& out, HasID& x) {
    out << ", ID=" << x.getID();
}

// printBase for HasColor
template <>
void printBase(std::ostream& out, HasColor& x) {
    out << ", color=" << x.color;
}

// Recursive step of printBases
template <typename Derived, typename Base, typename ... Bases>
void printBases(std::ostream& out, Derived& x, Base& y) {
    printBase(out, y);
    printBases<Derived, Bases...>(out, x, x);
}

// Base case of printBases    
template <typename Derived>
void printBases(std::ostream& out, Derived& x, Derived& y) {}

// ostream operator
template <typename ... Mixins>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Foo<Mixins...>& x) {
    out << "<Foo";
    printBases<Foo<Mixins...>, Mixins...>(out, x, x);
    return out << '>';
}
```

Main:

```c++
int main()
{
    Foo<> plainFoo;
    Foo<HasID> fooWithID;
    fooWithID.assignID(42);
    Foo<HasID, HasColor> multiTalentedFoo;
    multiTalentedFoo.assignID(1234);
    multiTalentedFoo.color = 0xff0000;

    std::cout
        << plainFoo << '\n'
        << fooWithID << '\n'
        << multiTalentedFoo << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
<Foo>
<Foo, ID=42>
<Foo, ID=1234, color=16711680>
```

Comment: Do you want to allow user defined base classes of your mixin? In this case there might be a trouble when two bases should affect each others behaviour. E.g. `Foo<IsFlying, IsSaucer>` might mean that your Foo object should be filled with extraterrestrial lifeforms, while `Foo<IsSaucer>` just mean it's coffee time... ;)

Comment: @W.F. User defined base classes should be allowed, although most often the user in "user defined" would probably be myself. ;)

I do see the issue of bases that should affect each other and it is not something I had anticipated. The use cases I was imagining were mainly adding additional attributes with little to none behavior.

Answer (score 2):

> My two questions about this code are as follows:
>
> Does this particular pattern have a name?
>
> What are the uses and drawbacks of using templates like this?

CRTP "curiously recurring template pattern" or sometimes also called "mixin".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Do we really want to discuss the drawbacks here again while the net knows this pattern/idiom? It is discussed enough :-)

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/123886/is-crtp-used-much-and-why-it-is-isnt

This article http://www.drdobbs.com/building-more-flexible-types-with-mixins/184402056 notes:

> The biggest drawback of the CRTP technique is that constructors aren't inherited. This means that if you use an initializing constructor in your implementation class, every extension will have to have an appropriate initializing constructor. This causes the extensions to be more restricted and, as such, less useful.

That is not longer true as for c++14 you have a good chance to kill that argument with variadic templates and chains of constructor calls for the base class(es). Inheriting & delegating constructors will also help for that purpose.

As with all templates you have to remember that each instantiation is a new type which can result in a lot of code duplications in your executable. I use this pattern very often and accept the cost. The alternative is to handcraft the code which is not less in executable size. You have to pay for what you need.

Comment: But is it really CRTP? CRTP manifests itself in the form of `class X : Base<X> {};`. That is different from what I'm describing, which (if you leave out the variadic part) has the form of `template <typename B> class X : B {};`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer the second part: Yes, this pattern has a name: [Static Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming#Static_polymorphism).

Comment: Hmm, the example on that page makes use of [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to eliminate vtables and the specification of what the base classes are is done at where the class is defined. In my example on the other hand, the base classes are specified at where the object is defined.